# pfSense monitor wan bandwidth by lan ip

Tags: pfsense

I think pfSense is great and has a lot of helpful features.  I use it for a lot of things but I cannot find one feature that I really need.

My Current setup is several Vlans and 1 Wan. We currently have a very low internet speed of 12MB.  The issue is this gets used up a lot.  I have the squid reports but it is very hard to tell who is hogging all the bandwidth at any given time.  The Traffic Graphs are great but the lan side shows interlan bandwidth along with wan but I need just wan usage by lan ip.

What I need is a list of local ips for each Vlan with bandwidth usage of Wan internet only in the past 5m, 30m or Hour.

Answer (score 1):

Install the pfflowd package and then set up a netflow collector of your choice on your network. Let it run for a few days, and then examine the stats. You should easily be able to extract the data you're looking for.

Comment: I was looking into those and have tested one out before but I am still very new.  Do you recommend one that is open source.  The one we tested was going to be several thousand and we don't have the need for something that crazy.

Comment: There are plenty of F/OSS netflow collectors. Just look through your distro's available packages.